# Find folder id on google drive by file id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table where a column contains the id of a google spreadsheet file. I need to find the folder where the given table is located and put its id in the adjacent column. I'd like to have a google script that I can run from my spreadsheet to do this kind of search. Unfortunately, I did not find how to get the folder id given the file id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to get the (parent) folder id given the file id

Given a Drive file, the method [`file.getParents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents) returns a *collection* ([FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)) of parent folders of that file (the method is plural because it used to be possible for a single file to exist in more than one parent folder, though Google has [deprecated that model](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multi-parenting), so it's likely that your file in question only has one parent).

Assuming your file has exactly one parent folder, we can use the FolderIterator class's `.next()` method to get that folder, so the following snippet will give the folder id, based on the file's  `fileId`:

```
var folderId = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next().getId()
```

Comment: Thanks!
The code works.
Note: My code breaks if I don't have access to the folder or file.

My function:

`function FindFolders() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //open active sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var fileId = ss.getRange("G" + i).getValue();  //column G of sheet shall have file ID
    var folderId = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next().getId();
    
    var setfolderId = ss.getRange("H" + i).setValue(folderId); //paste in column H Folder ID

  }
 
}
`

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can use a try...catch block to avoid the error when you don't have file permission.